# How to extract regex value from preg_split() function in PHP

Tags: php, preg-split

If I use `preg_split()` function for example:

```
$string = 'products{id,name},articles{title,text}';
$arr = preg_split('/\}\,(\w)/', $string);
print_r($arr);
```

I receive the following result:

```
Array ( [0] => products{id,name [1] => rticles{title,text} )
```

How to receive full word **articles** i.e. to extract the value of the regex pattern ?

ps. If it's possible at all

Comment: Might be a good idea here to give an example of what you are entering and what you expect to get back.

Comment: The string I'm entering is in my question. As you see now I receive **rticles** but I want to extract also regex value **a** and add it before the **rticles**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split on matching the curly braces, clear the match buffer. Then match the comma and use a positive lookahead to assert a word character on the right instead of matching it.

```
{[^{}]*}\K,(?=\w)
```

The pattern matches:

- `{` Match `{`
- `[^{}]*` match 0+ times any char except `{` and `}`
- `}` Match `}`
- `\K,` Forget what is matches until now and match a comma
- `(?=\w)` Positive lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is a word character

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BPyz6A/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/3ebbB)

```
$string = 'products{id,name},articles{title,text}';
$arr = preg_split('/{[^{}]*}\K,(?=\w)/', $string);
print_r($arr);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => products{id,name}
    [1] => articles{title,text}
)
```